# bash, grep issue with regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

From a given file I only want to retrieve lines having 'rt_view_product' then whatever then 'user_id'

My code is:

```
cat some_file | grep '"(rt_view_product)(.*)(user_id)*"' >> view_event.log
```

I know that 'some_file' has this kind of line but view_event.log remains empty

I also check my regex on https://regex101.com/ and it seems to work fine

here an example of a line of 'some_file':

```
/v1/events?os=android&bundle=test&event=rt_view_product&network=Organic&ip=0.0.0.0&time=1437352628&country=th&device_name=TRUESMART4.0&os_version=19&session=12&adid=d963faa323b2cd971467d7ddd63b5125&google_play_advertising_id=d9676bba-b664-4d0b-be3d-94e542e0768c&language=th&tracking_enabled=1&time_spent=1618&environment=production&timezone=UTC%2B0700&sdk_version=android4.0.5&device=Phone&device_model=TRUE+SMART+4.0&display_size=3.88&app_version=3.0.12&device_manufacturer=alps&gender=Male&product=ODFLKGJDFLKGJ&shop_country=TH&user_id=7474774
```

and idealy i would like to save:

```
7474774 (<= value of user_id),ODFLKGJDFLKGJ(<= value of product)
```

Comment: may be good to show some kind of sample input and desired output, so we can "play" with it

Comment: Are you intentionally adding the double quotes (in other words, are they part of the match)?

Comment: it is still not clear how your output should look like. Mind to clarify it?

Comment: The behaviour of regular expressions isn't universal, so I would recommend against using regex101 to test solutions for languages outside the ones listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use parenthesis:

```
$ echo "rt_view_product something user_id" > foo
$ grep 'rt_view_product.*user_id' foo
rt_view_product something user_id
```

https://regex101.com/r/sG0bW3/1

Comment: You don't need a useless use of cat either ;)

Comment: Or if you only need the product and user_id use this command example: grep -o "product=[A-Z]*\|user_id=[0-9]*" some_file | sed 's/product=\|user_id=//g' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'

Comment: Not only do you not need parentheses; they are wrong for `grep`. (If you need grouping parentheses, they need to be backslashed.) You can change the regex dialect with `grep -E` or even, with GNU, `grep -P`. The latter will give you the  dialect supported by regex101.